# Call to undefined function session_set()

Tags: php, session

My page returns this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_set()>in /home/a7714221/public_html/index.php on line 5

My code is long on the page that returns the error but the only thing that could cause it of course is the session_set()

Anybody know the fatal error that I've inadvertently made? :)

EDIt: I'm trying to pass variables across several pages. Specifically, take $_POST data, subtract it from another variable then ask the user to enter another value and subtract it from (previous post data - afore mentioned variable) and so on until it reaches 0.

Comment: There's no such function in PHP. What is it supposed to do? If you post your code, maybe we can guess what function you meant to call.

Comment: Well... Couldn't you put only the snippet code which this function is related?

Comment: It's a multipage thing - although I have elaborated in the edit @Barmar

Comment: That's what sessions are used for, but it doesn't explain what you expect `session_set` to do. Please show the code that uses this function.

Comment: There's a function `session_set_cookie_params()` and `session_set_save_handler()`. Those are the only similar functions I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function session_set(), hence the fatal error. You tried to call a function that does not exist.

To set a session variable, you access it via the $_SESSION array.

So to set a $_SESSION variable, just like any other array

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';

# Access a session var
echo $_SESSION['foo'] # Prints 'bar'
```

[Further Reading from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)